# goのGUI開発ライブラリFyneをgo getするが build constraints exclude all Go files となりデモアプリを起動できない

Tags: go

Fyneのデモを試そうと以下のコマンドを実行しました。

```
$ go get fyne.io/fyne
$ go get fyne.io/fyne/cmd/fyne_demo
$ fyne_demo
```

以下のようになり、デモアプリを起動できませんでした。
ビルドからファイルが除外されていると言われているようなのですが、
これはどうすればよいのでしょうか。

```
root@eac7eca8f1ef:~/dev/app# go get fyne.io/fyne    
go: downloading fyne.io/fyne v1.4.3
root@eac7eca8f1ef:~/dev/app# go get fyne.io/fyne/cmd/fyne_demo
go: downloading github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify v1.4.9
go: downloading github.com/fyne-io/mobile v0.1.2
go: downloading github.com/godbus/dbus/v5 v5.0.3
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200720211630-cb9d2d5c5666
go: downloading github.com/goki/freetype v0.0.0-20181231101311-fa8a33aabaff
go: downloading github.com/srwiley/oksvg v0.0.0-20200311192757-870daf9aa564
go: downloading github.com/srwiley/rasterx v0.0.0-20200120212402-85cb7272f5e9
go: downloading golang.org/x/image v0.0.0-20200430140353-33d19683fad8
go: downloading github.com/stretchr/testify v1.5.1
go: downloading github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw v0.0.0-20200625191551-73d3c3675aa3
go: downloading golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20200324143707-d3edc9973b7e
go: downloading github.com/go-gl/gl v0.0.0-20190320180904-bf2b1f2f34d7
go: downloading github.com/davecgh/go-spew v1.1.1
go: downloading github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0
go: downloading gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.2.8
go: downloading golang.org/x/text v0.3.2
fyne.io/fyne/cmd/fyne_demo imports
        fyne.io/fyne/app imports
        fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw imports
        github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw: no Go source files
fyne.io/fyne/cmd/fyne_demo imports
        fyne.io/fyne/app imports
        fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw imports
        fyne.io/fyne/internal/painter/gl imports
        github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.2-core/gl: no Go source files
package fyne.io/fyne/cmd/fyne_demo
        imports fyne.io/fyne/app
        imports fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw
        imports fyne.io/fyne/internal/painter/gl
        imports github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.2-core/gl: build constraints exclude all Go files in /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-gl/gl@v0.0.0-20190320180904-bf2b1f2f34d7/v3.2-core/gl
package fyne.io/fyne/cmd/fyne_demo
        imports fyne.io/fyne/app
        imports fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw
        imports github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw: build constraints exclude all Go files in /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw@v0.0.0-20200625191551-73d3c3675aa3
```

以下環境設定です。Goのバージョンは1.16.5です。

```
root@eac7eca8f1ef:~/dev/app# go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/root/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/root/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/root/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/root/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/opt/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/opt/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.16.5"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="0"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build693209325=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Comment: @uyugineer ちなみに、今 Fyne は v2 をリリースしていて、README に書かれているインストール方法も v2 準拠になっています。v1 である必要が無いのであれば v2 で動かないでしょうか https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne#prerequisites

Comment: gccをインストールしたところ解決しました。
v2で動作しました。
ありがとうございました！